# How can I print accuracy of the model in a different way?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am carrying out supervised machine learning. At present, by using scikit's metrics, it prints out the accuracy of the entire corpus.

I also wish to print out the accuracy of top 3 topics and then top 5 topics. How can I do so?

```
model = LogisticRegression()
model = model.fit(matrix, label)
y_train_pred = model1.predict(matrix_test)
print(metrics.accuracy_score(label_test, y_train_pred))
```

Comment: Are you using a particular library to do this?

Comment: @xuhdev: yes scikit-learn.. I am importing metric from scikit-learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a **confusion matrix**: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html

Example: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html

This way you get specific information applied to each category prediction.

Comment: Btw, you can also obtain a numerical view of accuracy and different metrics by category by using the `classification_report` http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html